# How To Write Series Of Number In Excel

Tags: excel

I want to write numbers in excel starting from `000001` till 999999

I have done like this =**TEXT(A2,"000001")** but i am not been able to generate series even though not able to separate this in different attributes

Further I want to distribute each number in each different cell for example like this

```
A           B         C        D         E         F       G                       


000001      0         0        0         0         0       1     

000002      0         0        0         0         0       2



till


999999      9          9       9         9          9       9
```

Comment: is there any formula to do that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried already? :)

Comment: i have did like this =TEXT(A2,"000001")

Answer (score 3):

Use following formuls to `B1` cell and drag then right and down as needed.

```
=MID($A1,COLUMNS($A$1:A$1),1)
```

***See the screenshot.***
[image]

Comment: this is working but how to generate series from 000001 to 999999

Comment: Enter this formula `=REPT("0",6-LEN(ROW()))&ROW()` to `A1` cell then drag down till `Row` 999999.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better way:

1. In cell `A1`, type 1.
2. Select `A1` and from **Home** tab, choose **Fill** > **Series** (top-right).
3. Choose **Columns**; **Linear**; set **Step Value** to `1` and **Stop Value** to `999999` or whatever you want. Click OK.

   [image]
4. Use AutoFill feature to fill up to the number you want.
5. Right-click column `A` header and choose **Format Cells**.
6. Choose Custom formatting and type `000000` in the custom format type textbox.
7. Click OK. Your cells will now show 000001, 000002, ... and so on.
8. In cell `B1`, type the following formula:

   ```
   =INT(MOD($A1/(POWER(10, 7- COLUMN())), 10))
   ```
9. Copy `B1` to columns `C1` through `G1`.
10. Copy range `B1:G1` to all subsequent rows `B2:G999999` or whatever.

### Notes

- One advantage of this approach is that column `A` is numeric, not text, so you can enter any 6-digit (or less) integer in it directly from keyboard and the cells will update themselves correctly.
- Column `A` will adjust number of leading zeros automatically for 6-digits or smaller numbers.
- The formula simply divides the number in column A by 10, 100, 1000 and so on and then takes remainder by 10, to get the corresponding digit at that decimal place.
- You can easily modify this formula to work with larger or smaller numbers. You simply need to replace `7` by (maximum number of digits in your number + 1).

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit easier with a VBA macro. Right-click the sheet tab, select View Code, paste the below code, and Run (F5)

```
Sub fill()
    [a1:a999999] = "=text(row(), ""000000"")"
    [b1:g999999] = "=mid($a1, column()-1, 1)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> - (Write this formula in Column `A` and extend it down to row `999999`)

### generating the series:

`=RIGHT(10^6, 6-LEN(ROW(A1)))&ROW(A1)`

> - Write this formula in Column `B` and extend it to Column `G`, then
>     extend the range of `B1:G1` to `B999999:G999999`

### Distributing digits

`=MID($A1,COLUMN(A1),1)`